# Issues with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hey guys so i already installed matplotlib. Whenever i run the command to install it i get this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in 

c:\users\gianc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\gianc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\gianc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\gianc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\gianc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from matplotlib) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\gianc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\gianc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\gianc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.15.0)
```

So it looks like its already installed. However, whenever i try importing it with
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
i get this error

```
File "d:/Documents/Python2/ranhw.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Any clue as to what might be happening here?

Comment: You seem to have installed it for python3.8, but are trying to import it  in python2.

Comment: This is my python version though: 
PS D:\Documents\Python2> python
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Also note that importing `pylab` isn't recommended anymore. See the [faq](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related). *pylab is a convenience module that bulk imports matplotlib.pyplot (for plotting) and numpy (for mathematics and working with arrays) in a single name space. Although many examples use pylab, it is no longer recommended.*

Comment: Perhaps you aren't importing it in Python2 then, But evidently you have more than one Python installation on your machine and the one that is executing your code is not the one that has matplotlib installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed matplotlib for Python 3.8, but are trying to use it in Python 2.

Run `pip2 install matplotlib` instead.